# C# LINQ - Join two lists based on First Come First Serve Order

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to be able to join these two lists and return the following pairings using LINQ.

The first occurrence of Test1 joins with first occurrence of Test2, then so on.

{ part = 1 , job = "A"}, { part = 1, job = "D" }

{ part = 1 , job = "B"}, { part = 1, job = "E" }

{ part = 1, job = "C" }, { part = 1, job = "F" }

Any help will be appreciated.

```
        List<Test1> test1 = new List<Test1>();
        test1.Add(new Test1() { part = 1 , job = "A"});
        test1.Add(new Test1() { part = 1 , job = "B"});
        test1.Add(new Test1() { part = 1, job = "C" });

        List<Test2> test2 = new List<Test2>();
        test2.Add(new Test2() { part = 1, job = "D" });
        test2.Add(new Test2() { part = 1, job = "E" });
        test2.Add(new Test2() { part = 1, job = "F" });

public class Test1
{
    public int part { get; set; }
    public string job { get; set; }
}

public class Test2
{
    public int part { get; set; }
    public string job { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so, the `Zip` method?

Comment: please share your epected output?

Comment: one of so many approaches: `list1.Select((x, i)=> new List<Test>{x, list2[i]});`

Comment: Thank you Gun and Daniel for replying. I was unfamiliar with the Zip function but that gave me the exact output I was needing and learned something new. Thank you again Gun.